# IE 8 - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm working on old IE Compatibility, specially IE 8.
But, my JS is not working ->
I got the `Object doesn't support this property or method` error on my item **item_tracked**

```
;(function () {
setTimeout(function () {
    currentItems().forEach(function (item_tracked) {
        /* item_tracked here */
        $(item_tracked.getView()).addClass('animated');
        /* item_tracked problem here */
    });
  }, 500);
})();
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `currentItems()` returns an Array, your problem is that IE8 does not support [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

You could substite a `for` loop or use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).